# Bakery algorithm (deadlock?)

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, for-loop, deadlock

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport%27s_bakery_algorithm

I have some problems to understand this algorithm. What happens if the current thread and the thread, I am looking at the moment in the for loop are the same?

Threads: 0, 1, 2

Thread 1 takes ticket 1. Thread 2 takes ticket 2. Thread 0 does nothing.

Array = i: 0, 1, 2

Round 1:

- Thread 1 (j=0): Array[0] = 0. next.
- Thread 2 (j=0): Array[0] = 0. next.

Round 2:

- Thread 1 (j=1): Array[1] = 1. (1,1) > (1,1)
- Thread 2 (j=1): Array[1] = 1. (1,1) > (2,2)

(1,1) > (1,1) wrong.
(1,1) > (2,2) wrong.

Both threads are waiting...

What's wrong? Is this a deadlock?

Comment: What does this mean: (1,1) > (1,1)?

Comment: (a, b) < (c, d) ... (a < c) or ((a == c) and (b < d))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The while loop in the algorithm allows a thread to enter critical section when the inequality does **not** hold. It says: wait as long as the condition (Number[j] != 0) && ((Number[j], j) < (Number[i], i) is true.

Since (1,1) is not greater than (1,1) the thread 1 can pass the loop and enter the critical section.

Comment: I got it but I also found another algorithm with "await((number[j] = 0) or (number[j], j) > (number[i], i))" instead of the while loop. Is it here the same? I can understand it with while, but not with this await.

Comment: Juan: I think it should be await((number[j] = 0) or (number[j],j) >= (number[i], i)), otherwise there is a deadlock as you said.

Comment: Juan: When i=j, surely number[j] /= 0 as it was initialized at the beginning, and (number[j],j) == (number[i],i), and these numbers cannot be influenced by any thread, so the i-th thread will be stuck. So that version is not correct.